# error when handling POST containing JSON with Play2 + Spray

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, spray

After looking for a ton of tutorials and posts and not being able to solve this apparently trivial problem, I am hoping that Stackoverflow comes to my rescue yet again.

I am trying to receive a JSON with a POST in my Scala + Play2 + Spray application, parse it and store it. I have structured the things in different classes, trying to keep the controller clean:

Object definition: ElementManager.scala

```
case class Element (id:Int, paramOne:String){
  override def toString = id.toString + ": " + paramOne 
}

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object ElementJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Element] {
    def write(e: Element) = JsObject(
      "id" -> JsNumber(e.id),
      "paramOne" -> JsString(e.paramOne))

    def read(value: JsValue) = {
      value.asJsObject.getFields("id", "paramOne") match {
        case Seq(JsNumber(id), JsString(paramOne)) =>
          new Element(id.toInt, paramOne)
        case _ => throw new DeserializationException("problem deserializing Element ")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Controller. ElementController . It has been copied from https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJsonRequests

```
@Singleton
class JsonController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents, storage:ElementManager) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def storepost = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val elementResult = request.body.validate[Element]
    elementResult.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" ->"KO", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))
      },
      element => {
        Element.save(element)
        Ok(Json.obj("status" ->"OK", "message" -> ("Element '"+element.id+"' saved.") ))
      }
    )
  }
```

Call:

```
curl  --header "Content-type: application/json"  --request POST   --data '{"id": 3, "paramOne":"test"}'  http://localhost:9000/storepost
```

Method "storepost" is supposed to receive a JSON, parse it into an Element and store. However, I keep receiving the following error.

```
Json deserializer found for type services.Element. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
[error]     val elementResult = request.body.validate[Element]
```

What is going on? Why the "read" function I have implemented is not valid to parse this? Should I implement a "Reads" beside the "read" function? (this does not look really elegant though). Is there any better way of getting the information of a POST parsing it?

Bonus question: would the answer be different with a "PUT" method? I am assuming not, but I will have to use it for some other things in my project...

cheers!

Comment: Did you import your implicit format in scope of controller method?

Answer (score 0):

use formats for serializing and deserializing:

```
implicit val formatElement = Json.Format[Element]
```

And then you can `use request.body.validate[Element]`

This will work.